# How to change URL structure using Polylang with multisite?

Tags: wordpress, multisite, polylang

I have four websites under one dashboard using Multisite feature of Wordpress:

```
example.com/
example.com/finance/
example.com/health/
example.com/science/
```

I used Polylang plugin to have both English and Persian versions since each website is going to have contents in both languages.

The problem is that URL structure is as below:

```
example.com/finance/fa/
example.com/health/fa/
example.com/science/fa
```

But I want them like these:

```
example.com/fa/finance/
example.com/fa/health/
example.com/fa/science/
```